# translating website in fluid app

Tags: fluid.app

I have created a fluidapp for a website in Spanish that I would like to automatically translate to English, preferably using the Apple Translate API (to which, I cannot locate a publicly available endpoint) or alternatively, Google Translate. How can I do this as fluidapp doesn't have the translate button that Safari has in its URL bar.